# Querying conceptual model with Entity SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Thought I read somewhere that you in fact can query your conceptual model with Entity Sql, using string based queries as such:

```
class DBSetTest<T> : List<T> 
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    public DBSetTest()
    {
        ObjectQuery<T> test = new ObjectQuery<T>("SELECT Name FROM Sessions WHERE  Name = 'sean'", db);

        foreach (var v in test)
        {
            this.Add(v); 
        }
    }     
}
```

Where 'Sessions' is a custom Entity Type I defined with a 'DefiningQuery'. I would otherwise query it with normal linq syntax. Does Entity SQL only query the store or can it query my conceptual model just like LINQ-to-Entities does? If so not sure I have the right syntax, since it probably isn't sql syntax.  My goal is to create a sort of custom generic list here, where I can write dynamic queries against my conceptual model.

I get the following error:

'Name' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 43.

Comment: Don't know about the custom types, but that isn't valid ESQL. Did you look? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399554.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think, It is not valid Entity SQL sintax, 
probably you must add some keyword like this :

```
SELECT VALUE s.Name FROM your_ObjectContext_name.Sessions AS s WHERE s.Name = 'sean'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get says that you must put it. before Name, like this:

```
"SELECT it.Name FROM Sessions WHERE it.Name = 'sean'"
```